# Change Font Awesome Icon Color When Input Is Clicked

Tags: css, input, colors, focus, font-awesome

I'd like to change the color of the font awesome icon inside the input fields when they are clicked. So far I've only managed to change the input border color when clicked, but can't figure out how to change the icon. Not sure why `input:focus i` isn't working. I've tried `input:focus .fa` as well and nothing. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#signInForm .input-icons {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-indent: 20px;
    padding: .1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #999;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#signInForm .input-icons i {
    color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    top: .15rem;
    left: .3rem;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input:focus {
    border-color: #00aef0;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input:focus i {
    color: #00aef0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div id="signInForm">
  <form>
    <div class="input-icons">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-icons">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: share your full code

Comment: my bad, forgot to include it when I posted. Just updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since your element has `position:absolute` and there is no previous selector, you can change the icon to make it after the input and be able to use the [`+` selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#signInForm .input-icons {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-indent: 20px;
    padding: .1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #999;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#signInForm .input-icons i {
    color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    top: .15rem;
    left: .3rem;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input:focus {
    border-color: #00aef0;
}

#signInForm .input-icons input:focus + i {
    color: #00aef0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div id="signInForm">
  <form>
    <div class="input-icons">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-icons">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So all I had to do was change the order!? Wow thanks so much! I would've never guessed that. Thank you!!

Comment: @eric not only the order :) i added `+` in the last selector ... by the way since the element is absolute position the order doesn't matter, so putting the element after allow you to consider next sibling selector as there is no previous selector

Comment: Good job! I actually tried doing the same thing, but first only with `+` and then by changing the order of the elements, but not both at the same time, so it didn't work.